Why use two arrays of insertion_time and lowest_insert_time in Tarjans algorithm for Bridges in Graph?
I've been working on the LeetCode problem 1192. Critical Connections in a Network. From various sources, I have the following code:
class Solution {
    int timer = 1;
    void dfs(int node, int parent, vector<int> &vis, vector<int> adj[], int tin[], int low[], vector<vector<int>> &bridges) {
        vis[node] = 1;
        tin[node] = low[node] = timer++;
        for (auto it : adj[node]) {
            if (it == parent) continue;
            if (vis[it] == 0) {
                dfs(it, node, vis, adj, tin, low, bridges);
                low[node] = min(low[it], low[node]);
                // node --- it
                if (low[it] > tin[node]) {
                    bridges.push_back({it, node});
                }
            } else {
                low[node] = min(low[node], tin[it]);
            }
        }
    }
public:
    vector<vector<int>> criticalConnections(int n, vector<vector<int>>& connections) {
        vector<int> adj[n];
        for (auto it : connections) {
            int u = it[0], v = it[1];
            adj[u].push_back(v);
            adj[v].push_back(u);
        }
        vector<int> vis(n, 0);
        int tin[n];
        int low[n];
        vector<vector<int>> bridges;
        dfs(0, -1, vis, adj, tin, low, bridges);
        return bridges;
    }
};

However, I'm struggling to understand why we use two arrays, tin[] and low[]. Since tin[] is used only to check if a bridge is present, can't we use low[] instead?
For example:
if (vis[it] == 0) {
dfs(it, node, vis, adj, tin, low, bridges);
low[node] = min(low[it], low[node]);
// node --- it
if (low[it] > low[node]) {
    bridges.push_back({it, node});
}

}
I don't understand the intuition for tin[]. Can someone provide an example where tin[] is definitely needed and explain why using only low[] would be incorrect? I am not asking about the usage of arrays in C++ but only to clarify the role of tin[] and low[] in Tarjan's algorithm, which should be language-agnostic.

"I don't understand the intuition for tin[]..." int tin[] is actually same as int *tin in a function parameter

I would also recommend writing it as int *tin instead of int tin[] as the latter is a bit misleading.

in c++ you don't need C-style arrays anyway. at least here

@user12002570 That is not the question; the question is about the function of the tin and low arrays in Tarjan's algorithm, not about C++ syntax. The duplicate does not make sense.

@Unmitigated I see, so this seems more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms

@user12002570 std::span, anything unsized is asking for problems.

@user12002570 It's still a valid question for Stack Overflow (especially considering it's more about the code): this is why the [algorithm] tag exists.

Make your question more focused, mentioning Leetcode doesn't help. Also expect comments about the style of C++ you use (if not for you, it is for other readers here). Your code style is not what experienced C++ programmers would use (an common factor with most code written by competitive coders)

@PepijnKramer Knowing the context is actually helpful for answering though.

@Unmitigated sure, but it would be enough just to focus on Tarjan's algorithm. Even independent of C++

So could be language-agnostic.

@Nikhil Did read  Tarjan's original paper.? Or even the wiki page? They both have an excellent explanation of the algorithm. I've implemented it once (for my job) and that code looked nothing like this. Basically if you want to understand an algorithm go back to the original paper (not code), because now you try to understand some code you copied from somewhere (with bad style and bad names which makes it hard to do)

@PepijnKramer This code looks like a very standard simple Tarjan's implementation to me (not considering style). If you're referring to the fact that it's not checking for cross edges, that is unnecessary in an undirected graph.

"I've been working on the LeetCode ..." - There's your problem, right there.

People marking this as a duplicate absolutely does not understand what you are asking. if (low[it] > low[node]) won't work as you are already updating low[node] in the loop. See the FAQ section of https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71146 for another reason why this won't work.
